# Kitchen Remodel: Cooktop Relocation

Tags: kitchens, remodeling, kitchen-island

Background:
I’m trying to remodel my kitchen and I want to replace the center island with a much bigger one with cooktop and remove the current stove and oven.

Question:
what are the common steps to relocate range hood and cooktop?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I did search for cooktop/range hood relocation but didn't find anything before I ask this question. My question specifically want to ask cooktop/rangehood relocation not about Kitchen remodeling in general. I am new here, so any suggestion in modifying my questions are welcome. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is _far_ too broad a question to be answered here. If you'll take the [tour] and look through the [help], you'll see what is on topic and what makes a good question. You've probably got about 10 good questions wrapped up in this one, please feel free to ask them all.

Comment: I did search for cooktop/range hood relocation but didn't find anything before I ask the question. My question specifically asks cooktop/rangehood relocation not about Kitchen remodeling in general. I am new here, so any suggestion in modifying my quesions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: What type of hood do you have, and is your cooktop gas or electric?

Answer (score 0):

You are not making any structural changes but you are making electrical and gas plumbing changes that will require permits and inspections.

First sketch out what you actually have.

Second sketch out what you want

Do a “planned modifications” breakdown for the circuits & plumbing (this sets the fees in my state)

Submit to building codes office for review with fee
Once approved pay full fees

Start work

In my state there is a rough inspection

Cover inspection

Final inspection

For remodels rough and cover are combined ;approves basic wiring / plumbing pathways. Box locations proper number and spacing, gas shutoff and pressure check.

Final verifies the work is completed and all GFCI devices actually function.

Your state may be different but those are what it takes in my state.
Note I have seen inspectors be real jerks to homeowners especially if they did not meet the basic requirements of required code so make sure to read up and ask questions extra inspections can get expensive.